# BOOT0 circuit design in STM32f446

Tags: stm32, design, pullup, pinout, pulldown

I'm designing STM32f446 chip in PCB in a project. It will be programmed through SWD.

but I'm stuck with (BOOT0) pin. I want it to be (0) as recommended.

The thing is that there is no enough info. about it.

I've looked at the data sheets to find the rating (voltage and current), I just found the voltage to be 9V !

I need to select the pull-down resistor, what should I do?

thanks,

Comment: Dig around on the ST website application notes, looking for bootloader applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm stuck with (BOOT0) pin. I want it to be (0) as recommended.
>
> [...]
>
> I've looked at the data sheets to find the rating (voltage and current), I just found the voltage to be 9V !

Section 6.2 in the [STM32F446 datasheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f446mc.pdf) shows that the *absolute maximum* voltage allowed on the `BOOT0` pin is 9V. **However**, a voltage above V<sub>DD</sub> is only used in one, rare, situation. In all other (i.e. normal) cases, you treat the `BOOT0` pin as a normal CMOS input (input voltage between V<sub>DD</sub> and V<sub>SS</sub>).

The one situation where that 9V maximum voltage is relevant, is because the `BOOT0` pin is also the V<sub>PP</sub> pin. One option for programming the internal Flash memory of the MCU (which is rarely used outside of mass programming on a production line) involves supplying an external V<sub>PP</sub> voltage on that pin.

That is the only time when V<sub>PP</sub> is applied to that pin, so that is the only time when the 9V maximum applies. See section 3.5.2 "Program/erase parallelism" in [Reference manual RM0390](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00135183.pdf) for your MCU.

> what should I do?

For each family of STM32 MCUs, ST produces a "Getting started with [...] MCU hardware development" application note. For your MCU, you need "[Application note AN4488 - Getting started with STM32F4xxxx MCU hardware development](http://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00115714.pdf)". That shows you how to connect the `BOOT0` pin for normal use.

If you don't ever want to change this `BOOT0` setting, you could tie that pin low (i.e. to your 0V rail), to force the MCU to always boot from your program in its Flash. However that will prevent you booting the MCU using its built-in bootloader (or from SRAM) in future, if your plans change. Therefore leaving the `BOOT0` pin as a logic high/low selectable option (e.g. via jumper pins or solder jumper etc.) may be sensible, as shown in the ST "Getting started" application note linked above.

Comment: What about the max. current sunk by `BOOT0`? Can't find any information on that in the datasheet.